# stored data sorting: nonclustered primary key overrides clustered index

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to create a table with a nonclustered primary key (to set foreign keys on other tables to it) and a clustered index to store the data in the intended order.

However, the resulting stored data is sorted in the primary key's order as opposed to the index's.

Is there a way to prevent this from occurring? Here is an example (SQL Server 14.0 RTM):

```
create table dbo.a (
     x nvarchar(50) not null
    ,y nvarchar(100) not null
    ,index ix_a clustered (y)
    ,constraint pk_a primary key nonclustered (x)
)

insert dbo.a
values
     ('d','p')
    ,('c','q');

select * from dbo.a
```

the result should be sorted with p first, then q. Howerver, q is in the first row and p is in the second row.

In a similar case, this approach worked when the primary key was in 2 columns as opposed to only 1 column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused.  This query:

```
 select *
 from dbo.a
```

Does not tell you anything about the "ordering" of a table.  A SQL table with no `ORDER BY` returns rows *in an indeterminate order*.  I also freely admit that with a handful of rows in the table, this would be highly correlated with the actual ordering of the data, but I strongly discourage you from thinking along those lines.

If you want to know the actual ordering, you need to peak at the data pages.  Or you can perhaps use an execution plan to see if an index is being used instead of a sort.

I think that what you are seeing is that SQL Server is choosing to return rows from the query using the primary key index.  With two rows in the table, the actual execution plan doesn't really matter.